# Splash screen to disappear after index is visited for the first time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, splash-screen

Well the Title sums up almost everything:

I have a Splash screen on my index.php, but i have no idea how to make it disappear since obviously i dont want it to show up each time index is loaded.
Just need a hint not asking for the job done

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a flag variable either in `localstorage` or `cookie` or `session`. If not set show the splash screen else skip.

Comment: Where should i set the flag? im having trouble hiding the div when the flag is set to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use local storage or a cookie to save a value that is checked in your code before showing the splash screen.  You can also use PHP sessions, but they probably won't last long enough for what you're looking to accomplish.